# Can I disable jslint's 'empty block' warning in Brackets?

Tags: javascript, jslint, brackets

I created the following isqrt function.

```
function isqrt(n) {
    var shift, result, candidateResult;
    if (n < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (shift = 2; n >> shift; shift += 2) {}
    for (result = 0, shift -= 2; shift >= 0; shift -= 2) {
        result = result << 1;
        candidateResult = result + 1;
        if (candidateResult * candidateResult <= n >> shift) {
            result = candidateResult;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

There is an empty block here.

```
for (shift = 2; n >> shift; shift += 2) {}
```

But this is intentional.
I know I can improve this code as follows.

```
shift = 2;
while (n >> shift) {
    shift += 2;
}
```

But I don`t want it.

I`m using the latest version of bracket on Windows 10. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the jshint rules for whole file or for particular line or for given block.

**Ignoring Line:**

```
function isqrt(n) {
    var shift, result, candidateResult;
    if (n < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (shift = 2; n >> shift; shift += 2) {} // jshint ignore:line
    for (result = 0, shift -= 2; shift >= 0; shift -= 2) {
        result = result << 1;
        candidateResult = result + 1;
        if (candidateResult * candidateResult <= n >> shift) {
            result = candidateResult;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Ignoring Block**

```
/* jshint ignore:start */
// Code here will be ignored by JSHint. So write your code here
/* jshint ignore:end */
// Code here will be linted with JSHint.\
```

or just write `// jshint ignore: start` at the start of file then whole file will be ignored

Comment: I tried but the warning is still active.
I don`t know what I missed. orz...

Comment: try adding `/*jshint noempty: true */` in your js file or add empty comment in your block like `{ // comment to ignore jshint error.}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

`for (shift = 2; n >> shift; shift += 2) {
     // do nothing.
}`

or Add following in your js

`/*jshint noempty: true */`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like

```
  /*jslint ignore:start**/
  for (shift = 2; n >> shift; shift += 2) {}
  /*jslint ignore:end**/
```